# Prove trigonometry identity for $\sec x -\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to prove this equality but I' stuck at the second step.

Please give me some hints or other ways to proceed.

\begin{gather}\frac{\tan^2x + \cos^2x}{\sin x+ \sec x} \equiv \sec x - \sin x \\
\sin x = 0 \\
\cos x = y \\
\frac{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+ \frac{y^4}{y^2}}{\frac{xy}{y} + \frac{1}{y}} \equiv \frac{1}{y} - x = \frac{1-xy}{y} \tag{1} \\
\frac{ \frac{x^2+y^4}{y^2} }{ \frac{xy+1}{y} }\equiv \tag{2} \\
\frac{x^2+y^4}{y(xy+1)} \equiv\tag{3}
\end{gather}

Comment: You might also want to remember that given your assignments of $x, y$, we have $x^2 = 1-y^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to see that $(x+y)(x-y) = x^2-y^2$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\tan^2{x} + \cos^2{x}}{\sin x + \sec x} &= \frac{\tan^2{x} + 1 - 1 + \cos^2{x}}{\sin x + \sec x} \\
&= \frac{\sec^2{x} - \sin^2{x}}{\sin x + \sec x} \\
&= \sec x - \sin x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Start by multiplying both sides by $\sin x + \sec x$ to get:

$$\tan^2 x + \cos^2 x = (\sec x - \sin x)(\sec x + \sin x)$$

And work the rest out from there :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^2(x)-1=-\sin^2(x)$$
$$\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)-1$$

$$\frac{\tan^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)+\sec(x)}=\frac{\left(\sec^2(x)-1 \right)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)+\sec(x)}$$

$$=\frac{\sec^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)+\sec(x)}=\frac{(\sin(x)+\sec(x))(\sin(x)-\sec(x))}{\sin(x)+\sec(x)}$$

I think you can do the rest from here. Though try not to substitute a function for the same variable (e.g. use $t=\cos(x)$ not $x=\cos(x)$)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Try writing the right hand side as a fraction over the same denominator, $\sin(x)+\sec(x)$.  Then see if you can manipulate the numerators to be the same.